# Annotator.js (API) loaded onto every React.js page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to develop a website that allows annotations (text annotation + dropdown selection). I am attempting to use [Annotator.js](https://github.com/openannotation/annotator), but I am running into some issues.

My website is built with React.js. I tried loading Annotator.js as specified on their documentation (code shown below).

When I land on the home page, the annotation tool doesn't show up when I select text. If I then go to the video annotation page, the annotation tool shows up when I select text. So far so good. However, when I then go back to the home page (or any other page on my website), the annotation tool shows up when I select text. That is not supposed to happen.

If anyone has any clue on how I could potentially solve this issue, advice would be greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import annotator from "annotator";

function VideoAnnotation({ transcript }) {
  var app = new annotator.App();

  app.include(annotator.storage.http, {
    prefix: "", //TODO: add database link
  });

  app.include(annotator.ui.main, {
    editorExtensions: [annotator.ui.tags.editorExtension],
  });

  app.start();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoAnnotation;
```

Here are the things I have tried so far:

(1) Look into the `beforeunload` event. I have tried using [react-beforeunload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beforeunload), as well as the code below. Neither have worked.

```
useEffect(() =>
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleWindowBeforeUnload)
);

const handleWindowBeforeUnload = (event) => {
    console.log("Before Unload"); //test if beforeunload event is detected successfully
};
```

(2) Looking into the [1.2 version](http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/v1.2.x/getting-started.html) of Annotator.js that allows you to load the annotator on a specific element. However, the documentation says it requires jQuery, and it is bad practice to use jQuery with React.js, I have heard.

(3) Try alternatives like [Hypothes.is' API](https://github.com/hypothesis/h), but that one also had a similar issue of loading on every page.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to use useEffect. It works now!